# WAMPServer 3.2.0: This site can’t be reached

Tags: wampserver

I have been using WAMPServer to run PHP and I am using port 8181 for that. Today, suddenly, I can't access localhost using WAMPServer and I get this message when I try to open a page at this address: http://localhost:8181/

> This site can’t be reached
> localhost refused to connect

Tried to change port but did not work.

Edit 1:
The WAMPServer icon is orange when I start it. I have tried to resolve this by clicking `Apache -> Service administration 'wampapache64' -> Install Service`. After that I have clicked `Apache -> Service administration 'wampapache64 -> Start/Resume Service`. Then I clicked on `Restart All Services`. Still, I see the same old orange icon.

Comment: Are you sure that WampServer was started and the icon was Green?

Comment: Why are you using a non standard port other than port 80?

Comment: The icon is orange. I think, port 80 was being used by another application at the time of installation of WAMP Server. When I initially tried to install WAMP Server, I couldn't use port 80 and so used port 8181. Everything was going fine, now, almost after 2 months, suddenly, this error is cropping up.

Comment: Look at the logs in `wamp64\logs` Find out WHAT THE ISSUE IS before trying to fix it

Comment: I am not sure in which of the 6 log files I need to look at. However, for the access.log file, I see `408`. In php_error.log file, I see the following error for today which have been there  from the beginning. `Apache variable '${INSTALL_DIR}' is not defined. May be there is syntax error in httpd.conf. Check it by right-click Wampmanager tray icon -> Tools -> Check httpd.conf syntax. May be Apache service 'wampapache64' is not started. Check it by right-click Wampmanager tray icon -> Tools -> Check state of services`.

Comment: So what did you change. What version of WAMPServer are you using

Comment: I am using WAMPServer version 3.2.0. Tried to change port by changing it in httpd.conf by changing `Listen 0.0.0.0:8181` and `Listen [::0]:8181`, tried to install and then start/resume Apache service by clicking `Apache -> Service administration 'wampapache64'` section.

Comment: Do you see something like `Define INSTALL_DIR c:/wamp64` in the  `httpd.conf` file around line 45

Comment: Yes, I see `Define INSTALL_DIR c:/wamp64` at line 45.

Comment: Did you not see the menu item `rightlclick wampmanager->Tools->Add a Listen Port to Apache`  In furture use that, it ensures the correct bits get changed, and you dont delete lines that you shoudnt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218161/discussion-between-shammun-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was facing was caused by an alias directory that I created earlier. This alias directory was located inside an external hard drive. The problem was I unplugged that external hard drive and tried to start WAMPServer. By right clicking on the WAMPServer icon and then by clicking on `Tools -> Check httpd.conf syntax`, I noticed this issue. So, I just plugged in the external hard drive and the problem is solved.