# Issue on localhost index page not working

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wampserver

I am using the wamp server locally, my project index page not working. However, this project is working perfectly fine on live hosting.

I find something in browser network were showing with stop icon **Provisional headers are shown**
I am attaching some pictures to define the issue easily.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This issue is most probably related to the configuration of your wamp server. Please check your wamp server logs, where you will find a description of the error. Without more information it is not possible to for the community to provide a clear fix.

Comment: I can share more information, can you tell me about the area that I should show?

Comment: You need to check your WAMP server logs, they will contain the information about the error you're facing.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the logs file. However, Just one in access.log file
:1 - - [03/Jun/2021:10:17:04 +0500] "GET /xxxxx/admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 301 -

Comment: Can you double check that you enabled PHP correctly on WAMP? Also please check this as it might be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983216/wampserver-3-2-0-this-site-can-t-be-reached

Comment: The above link that you send, I guess that is related to server service not working, Although my all server services working perfectly fine and my other projects working fine except this.

Comment: Try reading [The need for Virtual hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)